# Python xmltodict indicies error

Tags: python, xmltodict

I have this XML API I am trying to get information out of for stats. Here's my code and sample XML:

**xml.xml**

```
<calls total="1">
    <call id="cc04cd2a-31ff-422e-9f9c-94f41eaa219d">
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <coSpace>324f9508-beca-4829-89ee-927898c5796e</coSpace>
        <callCorrelator>45962153-c0ff-41ef-bf39-e75f54085b4e</callCorrelator>
    </call>
</calls>
```

**temp.py**

```
import xmltodict

totalNumCospaces = 0
totalNumCallers = 0

with open('/root/xml.xml','r') as f:
    xml = xmltodict.parse(f.read())

total = xml["calls"]["@total"]

totalNumCospaces = totalNumCospaces + int(total)
# If we have more than 0 calls active, find the coSpaces and count the callers
if (int(total) > 0):
    callList = xml["calls"]["call"]
    for c in callList:
        id = c["@id"]
        totalNumCallers = totalNumCallers + get_coSpaceCallers(server, id)
```

When I run the code and there are MORE than 1 `<call id="x">`stanzas, this works fine. If there is only 1 `<call id="x">`, then I get this error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 17, in <module>
    id = c["@id"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

When I print the contents of `xml`, I get this, so I know that `xml["calls"]["call"]["@id"]` should be there:

```
OrderedDict([(u'calls', OrderedDict([(u'@total', u'1'), (u'call', OrderedDict([(u'@id', u'cc04cd2a-31ff-422e-9f9c-94f41eaa219d'), (u'name', u'John Doe'), (u'coSpace', u'324f9508-beca-4829-89ee-927898c5796e'), (u'callCorrelator', u'45962153-c0ff-41ef-bf39-e75f54085b4e')]))]))])
```

Thoughts?

Comment: FYI - I have migrated this to the untangle Python library, which is very similar, but didn't give me this error during my testing.